# Python, print colored duplicates found in 2 list

Tags: python-3.x, colors

I'm 63 and just started with Python (My first steps with Udemy).
I'm Croatian so this is croatian language in program but you will understand when you run a program. I know it can be cleaner, shorter, more elegant etc, but as I mentioned before - I'm beginner.

---

```
import random

jedan = random.sample(range(1,99),15)
dva = random.sample(range(1,99),15)

def raspaljot(jedan, dva, i):
    for x in jedan:
        for y in dva:   
            if y == x:      
                index1 = jedan.index(x)
                index1_str = str(index1)
                index2 = dva.index(y)
                index2_str = str(index2)
                i += 1
                x = str(x)
                print(" Broj \033[31m" + x + "\033[0m,je dupli i nalazi se u listi jedan: na poziciji: \033[34m"
                + index1_str + "\033[0m a u listi dva na poziciji: \033[35m"+ index2_str + "\033[0m")
    print()
    print(jedan)
    print(dva)      
    if i != 0:
        print("\n *** Ukupno ima ", i, 'duplih brojeva. ***')
    elif i == 0:
            print("Nema duplih brojeva. :) ")

i = 0
raspaljot(jedan, dva,i)
```

---

What program do is finding duplicates in 2 random lists, them print duplicates in color and detecting position inside list[1] and list[2].
What I trying to do is printing list1 and list2 but showing duplicates in color.

For example:
[14, 78, 85, 31, 5, 54, 13, 46, 83, 4, 35, 41, 52, 51, 32]
[72, 40, 67, 85, 54, 76, 77, 39, 51, 36, 91, 70, 71, 38, 55]

here we have 3 duplicates (85,54,51). This above example on the console End was printed in white color, but I wanna these 3 numbers in red color in those two lines above.
Is this possible? I couldn't find a solution.

---

PS. Wing Pro version 7 on Fedora 33 Workstation / In WIngIde colors are only displayed in an external console and not the Debug I/O tool. :)

Comment: I think it is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. You want to print with specific colors on the console? That would not go down only to Python, but also the console/terminal settings, and the operational system even, probably.

Comment: Yes, like I can print duplicates in a specific color I'm looking for solution to print those duplicates (above 'For example; is output from 2 lists) in this output:   [14, 78, 85, 31, 5,... etc] is printed in white color, but in same line I wont to print 85 in a red color..

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be something like this:

```py
    # Change list to string
    jedan_str = str(jedan)
    # Create set with numbers that need new color
    num_set = {"85", "54", "51"}
    # Iterate over every number and wrap it with color change
    for i in num_set:
        # Note that I used f-string to format string 
        # But you can also do this as "\033[31m" + i + "\033[0m"
        jedan_str = jedan_str.replace("85", f"\033[31m{i}\033[0m")

    # Print string that represent list
    print(jedan_str)
```

Comment: Simply i wanna paint number 85 and 54 and 51 in red. When program run it produces output printing two list (all random numbers) so first printed list is [14, 78, 85, 31, 5, 54, 13, 46, 83, 4, 35, 41, 52, 51, 32] and a second which is printed below this one is [72, 40, 67, 85, 54, 76, 77, 39, 51, 36, 91, 70, 71, 38, 55]. In this 2 printed list on output console I wanna those 3 numbers in red color. So my wish is 14-white, 78-white, 85-red, 31-white... etc

Comment: I've updated my answer, is it what you looking for?

Comment: Close.The problem is - numbers {"85", "54", "51"} are always different. Sometimes no duplicates ( print("Nema duplih brojeva. :) "). Sometimes many duplicates. If you run a program you will see.

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea of using a set to determine which elements are in both lists (as [Cv4niak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11425694/cv4niak) proposed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66699427/12818877)), I created a function to print the output as you desire. There are numerous other ways of achieving it, but I think this is a simple yet effective way.

The idea is to use the `cprint()` function from the `termcolor` package. You can install it with `pip install termcolor`, and then print normally all elements, except the ones that are duplicates, which will be printed using `cprint(item, "red")`.

The `"{:0>2d}"` formatting in each `ìtem` print serves only to pad the number with zeros (so `2` will be printed as `02`, for example), in order for the output of both lists to be aligned.

```py
import random
from termcolor import cprint

def mark_duplicates(first, second):
    duplicates = list(set(first).intersection(second))

    if duplicates:
        for list_ in [first, second]:
            print("[", end="")
            for item in list_:
                if item in duplicates:
                    cprint("{:0>2d}".format(item), "red", end=",")
                else:
                    print("{:0>2d}".format(item), end=",")
            print("\b]")
    else:
        print("No duplicates.")


jedan = random.sample(range(1, 99), 15)
dva = random.sample(range(1, 99), 15)

mark_duplicates(jedan, dva)
```

With this, if there are no duplicates, the `No duplicates.` string will be printed. Also you can change the color with not much effort, and use other nice functionalities from `termcolor` package.